# how to write unit test case for kafka-node module in node.js

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

i was writing unit test case.Is anyone write the unit test case for kafka-node?

for e.g. producer.on ready event and consumer.on ready event.

Please provide some example.

Comment: Please follow this link https://dzone.com/articles/a-quick-and-practical-example-of-kafka-testing

Comment: this is related to java kafta testing . I am looking for node.js

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/colinfwren/testing-kafka-app-with-jest). This uses Jest

Answer (score 0):

I'm directly giving you the example in `nodejs`

Step 1: Create the topics

Our script auto-creates the topics if they do not exist using the following naming: `topic.0, topic.1`, etc. We hard code the number of partitions and replication factor both to 1. Feel free to change as required.

```
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({
    kafkaHost: kafkaHost
});
const admin = new kafka.Admin(client);
admin.createTopics(topicsToCreate.map(t => ({ topic: t, partitions: 1, replicationFactor: 1 })), (err, res) => {
    // ... test continues here
});
```

Step 2: Setup the producer connection and start publishing messages with the current timestamp as the key

We wait for the ready event from the producer before we start publishing. The key for each message is the current timestamp. This allows us to easily measure end-to-end latency in the consumer. We randomly generate each message to be between minMsgSize and maxMsgSize. We keep producing messages until `myDuration` milliseconds passes at which point we close and cleanup all connections after waiting 5 seconds to let all the consumers receive every record.

We use the testable-utils custom metrics API to increment a counter on each message published, grouped by topic.

```
const producer = new kafka.Producer(new kafka.KafkaClient({
  kafkaHost: kafkaHost
}));

producer.on('ready', function(err) {
  if (err)
    console.error('Error waiting for producer to be ready', err)
  else {
    log.info('Producer ready');
    produce();
  }
});

function produce() {
  for (var j = 0; j < producersPerUser; j++) {
    const topic = producerTopics[j % producerTopics.length];
    const msgLength = Math.ceil((maxMsgSize - minMsgSize) * Math.random()) + minMsgSize;
    results(topic).counter({ namespace: 'User', name: 'Msgs Produced', val: 1, units: 'msgs' });
    producer.send([ {
      topic: topic,
      messages: [ randomstring.generate(msgLength) ],
      key: '' + Date.now()
    } ], function(err) {
      if (err) {
        log.error(`Error occurred`, err);
      }
    });
  }
  if (Date.now() - startedAt < myDuration)
    setTimeout(produce, msgFrequencyMsPerTopic);
  else
    setTimeout(complete, 5000);
}
```

Step 3: Consume messages and capture the E2E latency

Each virtual user will form its own consumer group for consuming messages. To get a unique name we will utilize the test run ID (i.e. execution) and the unique global client index assigned to each virtual user at test runtime. These will both default to 0 when run locally.

We use the message key to figure out the end-to-end latency from producing the message until it is consumed and record that as a custom timing metric. And just like we recorded a count of messages produced, we also capture a counter for messages consumed, grouped by topic.

```
const consumer = new kafka.ConsumerGroup({
  groupId: execution + '.user.' + info.globalClientIndex,
  kafkaHost: kafkaHost,
  autoCommit: true,
  autoCommitIntervalMs: 1000,
}, consumerTopics);

consumer.on('message', function(message) {
  results(message.topic).counter({ namespace: 'User', name: 'Msgs Consumed', val: 1, units: 'msgs' });
  results(message.topic).timing({ namespace: 'User', name: 'E2E Latency', val: Date.now() - Number(message.key), units: 'ms' });
});
```

Step 4: Close all connections

Once the desired duration has passed we need to cleanup all connections to end the test:

```
producer.close(function() {});
consumer.close(function() {});
client.close(function() {});
```

Running the test locally
The kafka-example-loadtest project comes with a script to easily run the test locally. You simply need Node.js 8.x+ installed.

./run-local.sh [kafka-url]
This will run one virtual user and print out any custom metrics to the command line.

Running the load test on Testable
Run the test at scale on the Testable platform. You need to sign up for a free account and create an API key. The test parameters in the start script were chosen to fit within the limits of our free account so that anyone can run this test.

The test will run for 15 minutes starting at 5 virtual users and stepping up to 50 virtual users by the end. It will publish to 10 topics with 5 producers and 5 producers per topic. Each publisher will publish every 500ms a random message between 100-500 bytes. The load will be generated from 1 t2.large instance in AWS N Virginia. The test results will use a custom view by default that features our custom metrics (E2E Latency, Msgs Produced, Msgs Consumed).

To run the test:

export TESTABLE_KEY=xxx
./run-testable.sh [kafka-url]
The script will output a link where you can view the results in real-time. The results will include the widgets shown below.

The run-testable.sh script can be customized with different parameters as required. All the API parameters can be found here.

```
curl -s -F "code=@test.js" \
  -F "start_concurrent_users_per_region=5" \
  -F "step_per_region=5" \
  -F "concurrent_users_per_region=50" \
  -F "duration_mins=15" \
  -F "params[kafkaHost]=$1" \
  -F "params[topics]=10" \
  -F "params[producersPerTopic]=5" \
  -F "params[consumersPerTopic]=5" \
  -F "params[msgFrequencyMsPerTopic]=500" \
  -F "params[minMsgSize]=100" \
  -F "params[maxMsgSize]=500" \
  -F "conf_testrunners[0].regions[0].name=us-east-1" \
  -F "conf_testrunners[0].regions[0].instance_type=t2.large" \
  -F "conf_testrunners[0].regions[0].instances=1" \
  -F "testcase_name=Kafka Load Test" \
  -F "conf_name=5-50 Concurrents 1 Instance" \
  -F "scenario_name=Node.js Script" \
  -F "view=@kafka-view.json" \
  https://api.testable.io/start?key=$TESTABLE_KEY
```

And that’s it! Play around with all the parameters to adjust the load profile.

Comment: It's better to answer the question directly here, rather than link out to an article. From the SO guidelines: "Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself.".

Comment: @RobinMoffatt edited my answer.Thanks for your suggestion and reminding me about SO guidelines

Comment: Isn't this an Integration test, unit test should be probably like mocking out Kafka client and getting whatever we need from there?
I'm confused.